# FB: obtain access token for public page reading

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I would like to read the data (in particular events) of a facebook public page (that are viewable without logging on facebook).
I get the app-token, following these steps:

1.
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=LOCATION

2.
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=LOCATION&code=CODE_OBTAINED

This procedure only works if I'm logged into my facebook account. Otherwise when i reach the url in step 1, i get redirected to facebook login page. But i want to retrieve these data without logging. It is possible? I should generate a new token dinamically for each user who uses the site or the application related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don´t need to "generate" an App Access Token, it´s only "App-ID|App-Secret" (App ID and App Secret with a pipe sign in the middle).

Side Note: The App Access Token works for all unrestricted Pages. If the Page is restricted by age or location, you have to use a User Token of a User who is allowed to see the Page.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: So i have to use this hardcoded string (app-id|app-secret) instead of access token? But where? Directly in the interrogation? like this: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/<page_id>/events/?access_token=app_id|app_secret ? Or somehere else?

Comment: "instead"? that is an app access token. read the links in my answer, you need to understand the difference between the tokens. there´s not just one.

Comment: for example: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/<page-id>/events?access_token=app_id|app_secret